# Python/Pandas: Return all rows for an ID where the duration between dissimilar categories is below 60 minutes

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, python-datetime

Problem: Return all rows for an ID (1,2,3,4) if there is any instance where the time difference between dissimilar categories (A,B) for that ID is below 60 minutes.  This time difference, or 'Delta' should be the minimum between two dissimilar categories within the same 'ID'.

Example df:

```
ID  Category    Time
1   A          1:00
1   A          3:00
1   B          3:30
2   A          13:00
2   B          13:15
2   B          1:00
3   B          12:30
3   B          12:00
4   A          1:00
4   B          3:00
4   B          4:00
4   B          4:30
```

Desired Output.  Note that event 2 B 1:00 is included because ID 2 does have an instance where a time difference between dissimilar categories was <=60.

```
ID  Category    Time        Delta(minutes)
1   A           1:00        150
1   A           3:00        30
1   B           3:30        30
2   A           13:00       15
2   B           13:15       15
2   B           1:00        120
```

Not this because there is no duration between dissimilar categories:

```
ID  Category    Time    Delta
3   B           12:00   n/a
3   B           12:30   n/a
```

Not this because Delta is not < 60min.

```
ID  Category    Time    Delta
4   A           1:00    120
4   B           3:00    120
4   B           4:00    180
4   B           4:30    240
```

I've tried using:

```
df["Delta"] = df["Time"].groupby(df['ID']).diff()
```

But this does not take into account Category.  Any assistance would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Your example does not match your description. Why is `3 B 12:30` not taken while there is another event `2 A 13:00` within an 60 minutes?

Comment: And why is `2 B 1:00` taken? Where did `Delta=120` come from? Please revise or explain.

Comment: Also, how should the difference be computed, in sequential order or chronological order?  Why are you taking records with `delta >= 60`? Please update the post and make sure every ambiguity mentioned above disappears.

Comment: Thanks Bill.  My intention was to only calculate differences within the same 'ID' but for dissimilar categories.  Rows for ID 3 would not be included because that ID does not have any dissimilar categories (both B).  Event 2 B 1:00 is taken because I would like to return all rows for an ID if the condition was met for that ID.  Apologies if my question was unclear, first post and am still learning.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H:%M')

def f(x):
    x1 = x.assign(key=1).merge(x.assign(key=1), on='key').query('Category_x < Category_y')
    x1['TimeDiff'] = x1['Time_y'] - x1['Time_x']
    return (x1['TimeDiff'] <= pd.Timedelta('60T')).any()
      
df.groupby('ID').filter(f)
```

Output:

```
   ID Category                Time
0   1        A 1900-01-01 01:00:00
1   1        A 1900-01-01 03:00:00
2   1        B 1900-01-01 03:30:00
3   2        A 1900-01-01 13:00:00
4   2        B 1900-01-01 13:15:00
5   2        B 1900-01-01 01:00:00
```

Comment: While it does not include 'Delta', I think that does it.  Now I just need to unpack and understand how you did it.  Thanks Scott!